# как запустить несколько браузеров selenium с разными параметрами в python

Tags: python, selenium

у меня есть функция которая открывает selenium браузер и выполняет определенные действия в  браузере на определенном аккаунте, а выбор в какой аккаунт заходить зависит от передаваемого числа.
так вот как мне запустить сразу несколько таких браузеров чтобы передавались разные числа в функцию. что то типа того что ниже но чтобы открывалось сразу несколько браузеров

```
for i in range(0, count_account):
    main_actions(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы попробовал запустить в отдельных потоках

Пример:

```
import threading

threads = []

for i in range(count_account):
    t = threading.Thread(target=main_actions, args=(i,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: благодарю работает

Comment: @YoungFire, пожалуйста :)