# Multiprocessing. При запуске одновременно двух браузеров, второй стоит в ожидании

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import json
import os
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool


'''options'''
# options.add_argument("--headless")


'''Authorization'''

# playlist_url = input("Введите URl playlist: ")

working_dir = os.path.sep.join(sys.argv[0].split(os.path.sep)[:-1])

with open(os.path.join(working_dir, "accounts.json"), "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())
    accounts = data["accounts"]


def auth_user(url):
    for account in accounts:
        try:
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={account['id']}")
            options.add_argument("user-agent=VKAndroidApp/4.38-849 (Android 6.0; SDK 23; x86; Google Nexus 5X; ru")
            # options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
            s = Service("/Users/valiev/code/python/vkbot_playlist/chromedriver/chromedriver")
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

            try:
                ''' Save session'''
                driver.get("https://m.vk.com/")
                time.sleep(2)

            except Exception as ex:
                pass

        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        finally:
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_count = 2
    url = input("Введите URl playlist: ")
    urls_list = [url] * process_count
    p = Pool(processes=process_count)
    p.map(auth_user, urls_list)
```

При запуске, код выполняется в одном окне, а второе окно просто открывает браузер но не выполняет код. Как сделать чтоб код выполнялся одновременно?

Comment: Будет очень полезно, если вы сократите свой код до [минимально воспроизводимого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). У членов сообщества Ваших json'ов нет, а времени на чистку кода может уйти уйма.

Comment: в json просто логины и пароли аккаунтов, цикл перебирает и авторизует их

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380859/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-selenium-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python

Comment: Не помогло, результат остался тем же